# sed randomized last digits using expression

Tags: regex, linux, sed

I need to parse a file and randomized the last digits for a given string when the pattern is found.

I am able to perform the desired result when using a simple case but it fails for a more complex case.

I am wondering what is wrong with the second case.

This example here works.

```
echo 'AB111-1-13' | sed 's/\(AB111\)-\([0-9]*\)-\([0-9]*\)/echo \1-\2-$(echo \3*$RANDOM | bc )/ge'
```

But this one doesn't work.

```
echo '<http://name/link#AB111-1-13>' | sed 's/\(AB111\)-\([0-9]*\)-\([0-9]*\)/echo \1-\2-$(echo \3*$RANDOM | bc )/ge'
```

Any ideas?

EDIT
This is the error message when trying to run the second example.

> sh: -c: line 0: syntax error near unexpected token `newline'
>   sh: -c: line 0:`'

Answer (score 1):

The GNU sed `e` flag executes the pattern space as a shell command.

In your first example your pattern space starts as `AB111-1-13` and becomes `echo AB111-1-$(echo 13*$RANDOM | bc )` which is a valid shell command and gets executed. (I should point out that `bc` is entirely unnecessary here as the shell can perform integer arithmetic just fine by itself `echo $((13 * RANDOM))`.)

But in your second example you pattern space starts as `<http://name/link#AB111-1-13>` and becomes `<http://name/link#echo AB111-1-$(echo 13*$RANDOM | bc )>` which is very much **not** a valid shell command and so, presumably, you get a shell error (would have been good of you to include it in the question though) when it tries to get executed.

So don't use `sed` for this. Use something that can evaluate arbitrary expressions like `awk` or `perl` or `python`, etc.

Comment: Thank you that is very informative. I had a perl version of this script but some of the files are too big to be processed by perl. I don't know if awk is able to perform this type of pattern matching. I will do some research using awk.

Comment: Perl is generally able to handle any file. There must have been something else wrong with your Perl solution. Just read a line at a time, precisely the way you do with `sed`.